# Type into two places at once

Tags: key-bindings, macvim

I am working in macvim with a latex file where I have an index where terminology is being stored (using `\usepackage{imakeidx}` and `\makeindex`).

I have a command for inserting terminology with emphasis and then indexing said terminology:

```
autocmd Filetype tex inoremap :nx \emph{<++>} \index{<++>}<++><Esc>01k<C-j>
```

The issue is that I have to type the same word or term twice which gets a bit annoying.

Is there a way of typing in both places at once?

Comment: Search this site for "multiple cursors". There's plenty of into about plugins as well as reasons for not using them and doing things in a more Vim way.

Comment: One example: [Multiple cursors at desired location](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4307/multiple-cursors-at-desired-location)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The one I linked/duped mentions vim-multiple-cursors...though it's in the _question_. Here's one that mentions the same plugin in an answer https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3165/edit-different-words-simultaneously-one-the-same-line-like-in-sublime-text-with/3173#3173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not a direct way, but you can use a command as a workaround.

I am assuming the `<++>` is the terminology you want to insert.

```
autocmd Filetype tex inoremap :nx <Esc>:NX<Space>
```

```
command! -nargs=1 NX execute "normal! i\\emph{".<q-args>."} \\index{".<q-args>."}".<q-args>."01k\<Esc>"
```

When you type :nx in insert mode, you will be prompted in the command-line mode (juste at the bottom of the screen) with the pending command `:NX` that is waiting for an argument to be given.

Exemple:

```
:NX Entry
```

will create:

`\emph{Entry} \index{Entry}Entry01k`

Infos:
`:help :command`
`:help <q-args>`
`:help :execute`
`:help :normal`

Comment: I like this command approach and it works.

Comment: The 01k isnt meant to be inserted literally; it’s a series of normal-mode commands