# Visual block - actions like in normal mode (jump to/find character)

Tags: visual-mode

Is it possible in **visual-block-mode** to use find next character?

Example:

1: select `"` in visual-block-mode:

```
code(|"|abcd").anotherCode()
code(|"|abcde").anotherCode()
code(|"|abcdef").anotherCode()
code(|"|abcdefg").anotherCode()
```

2.a: go to (find) next `"` symbol (or any other) and *select this symbols*:

```
code("abcd|"|).anotherCode()
code("abcde|"|).anotherCode()
code("abcdef|"|).anotherCode()
code("abcdefg|"|).anotherCode()
```

2.b: go to (find) next `"` symbol (or any other) and *select all text inside this symbols*:

```
code(|"abcd"|).anotherCode()
code(|"abcde"|).anotherCode()
code(|"abcdef"|).anotherCode()
code(|"abcdefg"|).anotherCode()
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this is the same as [How to achieve selection different length of texts on different lines](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2796/51)?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Visual-block mode only allows to select rectangular areas of text.

To achieve something similar to what you want, you may be interested in [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors). With this plugin you can create multiple cursors, where the commands you supply will affect each cursor. Thus you could create multiple cursors for the first row of `"`s, then apply the desired editing command, such as `df"`.